# Get max value from nested lists and transform into one list using stream

Tags: java, java-stream

League has 20 `Team`,  team has 11 `Player`, player has `int score` field.

```
 class Player {
        private int score;

        public int getScore() {
            return score;
        }
    }

    class Team {
        private List<Player> players;

        public List<Player> getPlayers() {
            return players;
        }
    }

    class League {
        private List<Team> teams;

        public List<Team> getTeams() {
            return teams;
        }
    }
```

Need to select from `List<Team>`  best `Player` with highest `score` and return one `List<Player>` including one best player from each team **using Stream**.

```
 public  List<Player> getTopPlayersFromEachTeam(List<Team> league) {
        // implementation
    }
```

Stuck at:

```
league.stream().map(Team::getPlayers).collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Any hints?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `Team` class could have a `bestPlayer` method

```
public Player bestPlayer() {
    return players.stream().max(Comparator.comparing(Player::getScore)).orElseThrow();
}
```

And in  the `League`, it would be easy to get the best player per team:

```
public List<Player> getTopPlayersFromEachTeam() {
    return this.teams.stream().map(Team::bestPlayer).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

---

Or all-in-one

```
public List<Player> getTopPlayersFromEachTeam() {
    return this.teams.stream()
            .map(t -> t.getPlayers().stream().max(Comparator.comparing(Player::getScore)).orElseThrow())
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

---

The `.orElseThrow()` code just means that if no `max` player can be found, for example if the list of players of one `Team` is empty

---

Test code

```
League l = new League(Arrays.asList(
        new Team(Arrays.asList(new Player(1), new Player(2), new Player(3))),
        new Team(Arrays.asList(new Player(10), new Player(20), new Player(30))),
        new Team(Arrays.asList(new Player(100), new Player(200), new Player(300)))
));

System.out.println(l.getTopPlayersFromEachTeam()); // [Player{score=3}, Player{score=30}, Player{score=300}]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do:

```
League league = new League(Arrays.asList(
        new Team(Arrays.asList(new Player(8), new Player(11))),
        new Team(Arrays.asList(new Player(15), new Player(12))),
        new Team(Arrays.asList(new Player(6), new Player(2), new Player(7)))
));

List<Player> bestPlayersInEachTeam = league.getTeams().stream()
        .map(team -> team.getPlayers().stream()        // Best from each team
                .max(Comparator.comparing(Player::getScore))
                .get())
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

System.out.println(bestPlayersInEachTeam);
```

Output:

```
[Player(score=11), Player(score=15), Player(score=7)]
```